# Slick slider is not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, slick.js

I have a problem with Slick carousel. It is not working with ng-repeat.
If I remove ng-repeat everything will works fine.

```
<section class="regular slider">
    <div ng-repeat="x in category">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div> 
</section>
```

My angular application is.

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('EntityApp', []);
    app.controller('EntityAppCntroller', function($scope, $http, $window) {         

          $http.get('http://www.abcdef.com:555/OpenApi/GetAllCategories', {
          }).success(function(response){
                $scope.category = response.res;                 
          });
    });
  </script>
```

Slick slider settings is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
      $(".regular").slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
</script>
```

Am getting output like..

```
[Image 1]
[Image 2]
[Image 3]
[Image 4]
```

Insteat I wanted `< [Image 1] [Image 2] [Image 3] >`

Comment: why you are trying with `document.ready` with `angularJs`. Better you can use module which having `slick` directive. for example: https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick

Comment: Why it will not work.?

Comment: `jQuery` loads before it. You can try using `timeout` but it does not prefer the way to use with `angualrJs`.

Comment: Ok can you demonstrate timeout with my code.

Comment: Do one thing, if you don't want to use those directives. Try to create your own directive where set `timeout`. See this https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick/issues/2 Here Someone solve your problem by creating own custom directive for setting time.

Answer (score 2):

Inject $timeout into controller, create a function called `initSlider`, then, inside your success callback, write `$timeout(initSlider);`

$timeout throws whatever callback is inside of it to the bottom of the callstack so it's guaranteed to fire after the ng-repeat has rendered. If you're using images you'll want to pair this with the imagesLoaded plug-in to make sure Slick can size itself correctly.

Watch [this](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=JC5vbignYnV0dG9uJywgJ2NsaWNrJywgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25DbGljaygpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGltZXIoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ1lvdSBjbGlja2VkIHRoZSBidXR0b24hJyk7ICAgIAogICAgfSwgMjAwMCk7Cn0pOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhpISIpOwoKc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0aW1lb3V0KCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkNsaWNrIHRoZSBidXR0b24hIik7Cn0sIDUwMDApOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlbGNvbWUgdG8gbG91cGUuIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D) to level up.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use "ng-if" if $timeout is not working.

```
<section class="regular slider" ng-if="category.length > 0">
  <div ng-repeat="x in category">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
  </div> 
</section>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the slick function after your data is loaded via angular Js. Here I give you a simple example.

**In angularJs controller:**

```
   $scope.getdata = function(){ 
                var url = "http://www.abcdef.com:555/OpenApi/GetAllCategories";
                $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                       setTimeout(sli,2);//calling sli function 
                }); <br/>
            }<br/>
```

**create a new function in your script:**

```
<script>
function sli(){ 
$(".regular").slick({ 
        dots: true, 
        infinite: true, 
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3 
      }); 
} 
</script>
```